# Limit li tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I there a way to limit dynamically added li tags to a specific number.
for example:-
I have given user ability to add li tags but dont want to give more than 3 li tags...

Comment: can you show your `addListTag` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created a sample fiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani10/VnfhE/)

Try something like :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var li_count = $('#sample li').length;
        if(li_count < 3)
            $('#sample').append('<li>HELOO YOU</li>');
        else
            return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: if it solves your problem , please do accept the answer :) @Hunain

Comment: can anyone answer this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907997/show-dynamically-added-navlinks-when-added-in-bootstrap-navbar

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter to your "add li" function. You can find the current number of li elements like this:

```
var numLis = $('#container li').length;
```

Comment: Why would you need a counter? Just compare to the `length` attribute directly.

Comment: the `length` attribute is the counter, yes. :) The discussion if you put it into a variable to make the if() statement look clean does not belong here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can group all the li tags under a div with an id "x-div".Then you could use the children count attribute to check for the count each time you add an li element.

Comment: `li` tags should already be grouped in a container - the `ul`

Comment: Ya, the id of the ul element could be used for the children count.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
if($('ul.myclass li').length > 3){
    alert('Not allowed to add more li');
}
```